# Xcode Assign shortcut keys to context menu items

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu, xcode

I want to assign a shortcut key to the "Jump To Definition" context menu item in XCode.

How?

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention which version of *Xcode* you are using, but here is how to do it in *Xcode* 2.5 (on 10.4/Tiger):

Since **Jump to Definition** is also an item in the **Find** menu, we can easily customize its binding. The item in the **Find** menu has the same effect as the menu item in the contextual menu. You can do this kind of main menu item key binding through *System Preferences* for applications that do not offer built-in binding customization.

1. **Xcode** menu > **Preferences…**

   - **Keybindings** section (horizontal scroll area at the top of the preferences window)
   - **Menu Key Bindings** tab
   - Click the disclosure triangle for **Find** (make it point down)
   - Find **Jump to Definition**, double-click in its **Key** column
   - If you have not previously changed any key bindings, it will tell you that the currently selected binding set is owned by the system. If this dialog comes up:

     1. Click the **Make Copy** button

        - Enter a name for your key binding set
        - Again, double-click on the **Key** column for **Jump to Definition**
   - Press the key combination you want to use (e.g. <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>).
   - Click on another line the **Action**/**Key** table to exit ‘key assignment mode’.
   - Click **OK** or **Apply** to activate the new key binding(s).

Comment: This works in the latest XCode as well (3.2.1 on Snow Leopard as of 1-25-2010).

Answer (score 1):

Or you could set it in your .pbxkeys keybindings file as something like

`<key>^i</key><string>jumpToSelectionDefinition:</string>`

Answer (score 0):

Although a little offtopic I found this article helpful since I was searching for a way to apply a shortcut ...

- [Using the Doxygen Helper in Xcode 4](http://www.duckrowing.com/2011/05/14/using-the-doxygen-helper-in-xcode-4/)